# Am I allowed to add user to a particular group upon installation of my package?

Tags: software-installation, application-development, security, deb

Suppose I've developed a program that requires that the user belongs to a specific group. I certainly can request a user to add themselves before installing my deb package,though I would prefer the process to be automated. The question is whether or not modifying user's information is an appropriate practice.

Are there regulations/security policies that specify what `.deb` packages can and cannot modify as far as end-user is concerned ?

Comment: I don't know of any specific policies, but as a matter of courtesy it is generally frowned upon to do *anything* on a user's behalf, such as going into their home directory, or modifying their system profile in any way, except upon their explicit request. Just because you think the user wants to be in that group and use that program does not mean they actually do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although not literally mentioning what you ask for, the spirit of what is the policy is clearly readable [here](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-files.html):

> "These scripts must be idempotent (i.e., must work correctly if dpkg needs to re-run them due to errors during installation or removal), must cope with all the variety of ways dpkg can call maintainer scripts, **must not overwrite or otherwise mangle the user's configuration without asking**, must not ask unnecessary questions (particularly during upgrades), and must otherwise be good citizens."

This implies imo that you should never make the installer change users/groups without explicitly asking for it. Preferably making him or her perform the action him- or herself.

Other arguments not to automate this:

- If errors occur, either on install or uninstall, consequences could be severe
- You should always consider to make sure the system is restored to how it was before your application was installed, if he or she decides to uninstall. Especially on users/groups, this can interfere with settings and profiles the user made for whatever reasons *after* he installed your application.

In short, I would be very, very restraint to automatically change users & groups.